# Как получить CellID с помощью 3g модема ?

Tags: c#, 3g

Есть десктоп приложение и 3g dongle. Как программно получить информацию о мобильных вышках, чей сигнал можно "услышать" с помощью модема ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищи мануал на модем смотрит AT команды, цепляйся на ком порт (Диагностик порт) отправляй команды и получай ответы.

Comment: Совет хороший! Но удалось найти команды что бы посмотреть инфу только о вышке к которой подключен. Но нужно инфы о всех .

Comment: Нужно активировать NetMonitor и будите видеть все вышки, не факт что у  Вашей модели есть такая функция, все нужно смотреть конкретно в мануале на железо.